# Extremely basic question about how shared objects are found and loaded

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ldd

I have a shared object library (well, technically a MATLAB mexfile) that links against other shared object libraries. When I run ldd on it, I see this:

```
[spocops@draco libs]$ ldd render_prf_collection.mexa64
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffeaf9e000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /nasa/pkgsrc/sles12/2018Q3/gcc8/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3d3420b000)
        libtess-common.so => /nobackupp15/spocops/git/draco/spoc/code/dist/libs/libtess-common.so (0x00007f3d34006000)
        libblas.so.4 => /home1/spocops/lib/libblas.so.4 (0x00007f3d33db2000)
        liblapack.so.4 => /home1/spocops/lib/liblapack.so.4 (0x00007f3d33523000)
        libmx.so => not found
        libmex.so => not found
        libmat.so => not found
        libtess-mod.so => /nobackupp15/spocops/git/draco/spoc/code/dist/libs/libtess-mod.so (0x00007f3d33307000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3d3300a000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /nasa/pkgsrc/sles12/2018Q3/gcc8/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3d32df3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d32a4e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3d34792000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f3d32725000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /nasa/pkgsrc/sles12/2018Q3/gcc8/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f3d324e6000)
        libmx.so => not found
        libmex.so => not found
[spocops@draco libs]$
```

Consider the example of the 3rd item in the output, libtess-common.so . My understanding is that, because ldd reveals that render_prf_collection.mexa64 has a location for libtess-common.so stored, it is not necessary to supply libtess-common.so in a directory that's on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. By contrast, libmx.so, libmex.so, and libmat.so are all not found, so in those cases some directory on LD_LIBRARY_PATH must contain the libraries or execution will fail.

Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a correct understanding?

No.

You can examine the info stored in `render_prf_collection.mexa64` with `readelf -d render_prf_collection.mexa64`.

You will observe that neither `libtess-common.so`, nor `libmx.so` have their locations stored inside `render_prf_collection.mexa64`.

Q. Why is it then that one of them is found, and one isn't?
A. We can't tell. You haven't provided enough info.

There are a few likely possibilities:

- you may have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set and it includes `/nobackupp15/spocops/git/draco/spoc/code/dist/libs` in it.
- you may have modified `ld.so.conf` to include `/nobackupp15/spocops/git/draco/spoc/code/dist/libs`.
- it may be that `render_prf_collection.mexa64` has `RUNPATH` or `RPATH` which includes `/nobackupp15/spocops/git/draco/spoc/code/dist/libs`.